# Scope issue between scripts due to multiprocessing

Tags: python, multithreading, scope, multiprocessing, queue

I am following this [tutorial](https://github.com/leigh-johnson/rpi-deep-pantilt). After cloning her repository and getting the "track" command to work, I wanted to try to integrate a scanning function.

I went into her manager.py script and added my scanning procedure in the `set_servos` function as shown below (in bold). This runs in the servos_process:

```
import logging
from multiprocessing import Value, Process, Manager, Queue

import pantilthat as pth
import signal
import sys
import time
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO

from rpi_deep_pantilt.detect.util.visualization import visualize_boxes_and_labels_on_image_array
from rpi_deep_pantilt.detect.camera import run_pantilt_detect
from rpi_deep_pantilt.control.pid import PIDController

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setwarnings(False)
GPIO.setup(8,GPIO.OUT)

logging.basicConfig()
LOGLEVEL = logging.getLogger().getEffectiveLevel()

RESOLUTION = (320, 320)

SERVO_MIN = -90
SERVO_MAX = 90

CENTER = (
    RESOLUTION[0] // 2,
    RESOLUTION[1] // 2
)


# function to handle keyboard interrupt
def signal_handler(sig, frame):
    # print a status message
    print("[INFO] You pressed `ctrl + c`! Exiting...")

    # disable the servos
    pth.servo_enable(1, False)
    pth.servo_enable(2, False)
    GPIO.output(8,GPIO.LOW)

    # exit
    sys.exit()

def in_range(val, start, end):
    # determine the input value is in the supplied range
    return (val >= start and val <= end)


def set_servos(pan, tilt, scan):
    # signal trap to handle keyboard interrupt
    signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, signal_handler)
    
    **
    #visualize_boxes_and_labels_on_image_array()
    print(scan.value) # output: 't'
    
    while scan.value == 't':**
        print('Scanning')
        pth.servo_one(90)
        pth.servo_two(25)
        time.sleep(10)
    
        pth.servo_one(30)
        pth.servo_two(25)
        time.sleep(10)
            
        pth.servo_one(-30)
        pth.servo_two(25)
        time.sleep(10)
        
        pth.servo_one(-90)
        pth.servo_two(25)
        time.sleep(10)
        
        pth.servo_one(-30)
        pth.servo_two(25)
        time.sleep(10)
            
        pth.servo_one(30)
        pth.servo_two(25)
        pth.time.sleep(10)
            
        pth.servo_one(90)
        pth.servo_two(25)
        time.sleep(10)
        
        continue
    
    while True:
        pan_angle = -1 * pan.value
        tilt_angle = tilt.value
        
        # if the pan angle is within the range, pan
        if in_range(pan_angle, SERVO_MIN, SERVO_MAX):
            pth.pan(pan_angle)
        else:
            logging.info(f'pan_angle not in range {pan_angle}')

        if in_range(tilt_angle, SERVO_MIN, SERVO_MAX):
            pth.tilt(tilt_angle)
        else:
            logging.info(f'tilt_angle not in range {tilt_angle}')

    
    
def pid_process(output, p, i, d, box_coord, origin_coord, action):
    # signal trap to handle keyboard interrupt
    signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, signal_handler)

    # create a PID and initialize it
    p = PIDController(p.value, i.value, d.value)
    p.reset()
    

    # loop indefinitely
    while True:
        error = origin_coord - box_coord.value
        output.value = p.update(error)
        # logging.info(f'{action} error {error} angle: {output.value}')
    

def pantilt_process_manager(
    model_cls,
    labels=('Raspi',),
    rotation=0
):
    
    pth.servo_enable(1, True)
    pth.servo_enable(2, True)
    with Manager() as manager:
        
        **scan = manager.Value('c', 't')**
        
        # set initial bounding box (x, y)-coordinates to center of frame
        center_x = manager.Value('i', 0)
        center_y = manager.Value('i', 0)

        center_x.value = RESOLUTION[0] // 2
        center_y.value = RESOLUTION[1] // 2
        

        # pan and tilt angles updated by independent PID processes
        pan = manager.Value('i', 0)
        tilt = manager.Value('i', 0)

        # PID gains for panning
        pan_p = manager.Value('f', 0.05)
        # 0 time integral gain until inferencing is faster than ~50ms
        pan_i = manager.Value('f', 0.1)
        pan_d = manager.Value('f', 0)

        # PID gains for tilting
        tilt_p = manager.Value('f', 0.15)
        # 0 time integral gain until inferencing is faster than ~50ms
        tilt_i = manager.Value('f', 0.2)
        tilt_d = manager.Value('f', 0)

        **detect_processr = Process(target=run_pantilt_detect,
                                  args=(center_x, center_y, labels, model_cls, rotation, scan))**

        pan_process = Process(target=pid_process,
                              args=(pan, pan_p, pan_i, pan_d, center_x, CENTER[0], 'pan'))

        tilt_process = Process(target=pid_process,
                               args=(tilt, tilt_p, tilt_i, tilt_d, center_y, CENTER[1], 'tilt'))

        **servo_process = Process(target=set_servos, args=(pan, tilt, scan))**
        
        
        detect_processr.start()
        pan_process.start()
        tilt_process.start()
        servo_process.start()
        
        detect_processr.join()
        pan_process.join()
        tilt_process.join()
        servo_process.join()
        
        
if __name__ == '__main__':
    pantilt_process_manager()
```

In a separate script called visualization.py, there is a statement in the `visualize_boxes_and_labels_on_image_array` function which is responsible for overlaying bounding boxes on the camera feed once an object is detected as follows (In bold towards the end). This runs in the detect_processr:

```
# python
import collections
import logging

# lib
import numpy as np
import PIL.Image as Image
import PIL.ImageColor as ImageColor
import PIL.ImageDraw as ImageDraw
import PIL.ImageFont as ImageFont
import six
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time
from time import sleep
import pantilthat as pth

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setwarnings(False)
GPIO.setup(8,GPIO.OUT)


STANDARD_COLORS = [
    'AliceBlue', 'Chartreuse', 'Aqua', 'Aquamarine', 'Azure', 'Beige', 'Bisque',
    'BlanchedAlmond', 'BlueViolet', 'BurlyWood', 'CadetBlue', 'AntiqueWhite',
    'Chocolate', 'Coral', 'CornflowerBlue', 'Cornsilk', 'Crimson', 'Cyan',
    'DarkCyan', 'DarkGoldenRod', 'DarkGrey', 'DarkKhaki', 'DarkOrange',
    'DarkOrchid', 'DarkSalmon', 'DarkSeaGreen', 'DarkTurquoise', 'DarkViolet',
    'DeepPink', 'DeepSkyBlue', 'DodgerBlue', 'FireBrick', 'FloralWhite',
    'ForestGreen', 'Fuchsia', 'Gainsboro', 'GhostWhite', 'Gold', 'GoldenRod',
    'Salmon', 'Tan', 'HoneyDew', 'HotPink', 'IndianRed', 'Ivory', 'Khaki',
    'Lavender', 'LavenderBlush', 'LawnGreen', 'LemonChiffon', 'LightBlue',
    'LightCoral', 'LightCyan', 'LightGoldenRodYellow', 'LightGray', 'LightGrey',
    'LightGreen', 'LightPink', 'LightSalmon', 'LightSeaGreen', 'LightSkyBlue',
    'LightSlateGray', 'LightSlateGrey', 'LightSteelBlue', 'LightYellow', 'Lime',
    'LimeGreen', 'Linen', 'Magenta', 'MediumAquaMarine', 'MediumOrchid',
    'MediumPurple', 'MediumSeaGreen', 'MediumSlateBlue', 'MediumSpringGreen',
    'MediumTurquoise', 'MediumVioletRed', 'MintCream', 'MistyRose', 'Moccasin',
    'NavajoWhite', 'OldLace', 'Olive', 'OliveDrab', 'Orange', 'OrangeRed',
    'Orchid', 'PaleGoldenRod', 'PaleGreen', 'PaleTurquoise', 'PaleVioletRed',
    'PapayaWhip', 'PeachPuff', 'Peru', 'Pink', 'Plum', 'PowderBlue', 'Purple',
    'Red', 'RosyBrown', 'RoyalBlue', 'SaddleBrown', 'Green', 'SandyBrown',
    'SeaGreen', 'SeaShell', 'Sienna', 'Silver', 'SkyBlue', 'SlateBlue',
    'SlateGray', 'SlateGrey', 'Snow', 'SpringGreen', 'SteelBlue', 'GreenYellow',
    'Teal', 'Thistle', 'Tomato', 'Turquoise', 'Violet', 'Wheat', 'White',
    'WhiteSmoke', 'Yellow', 'YellowGreen'
]


def _get_multiplier_for_color_randomness():
    num_colors = len(STANDARD_COLORS)
    prime_candidates = [5, 7, 11, 13, 17]

    # Remove all prime candidates that divide the number of colors.
    prime_candidates = [p for p in prime_candidates if num_colors % p]
    if not prime_candidates:
        return 1

    # Return the closest prime number to num_colors / 10.
    abs_distance = [np.abs(num_colors / 10. - p) for p in prime_candidates]
    num_candidates = len(abs_distance)
    inds = [i for _, i in sorted(zip(abs_distance, range(num_candidates)))]
    return prime_candidates[inds[0]]


def draw_mask_on_image_array(image, mask, color='red', alpha=0.4):
    if image.dtype != np.uint8:
        raise ValueError('`image` not of type np.uint8')
    if mask.dtype != np.uint8:
        raise ValueError('`mask` not of type np.uint8')
    if np.any(np.logical_and(mask != 1, mask != 0)):
        raise ValueError('`mask` elements should be in [0, 1]')
    if image.shape[:2] != mask.shape:
        raise ValueError('The image has spatial dimensions %s but the mask has '
                         'dimensions %s' % (image.shape[:2], mask.shape))
    rgb = ImageColor.getrgb(color)
    pil_image = Image.fromarray(image)

    solid_color = np.expand_dims(
        np.ones_like(mask), axis=2) * np.reshape(list(rgb), [1, 1, 3])
    pil_solid_color = Image.fromarray(np.uint8(solid_color)).convert('RGBA')
    pil_mask = Image.fromarray(np.uint8(255.0*alpha*mask)).convert('L')
    pil_image = Image.composite(pil_solid_color, pil_image, pil_mask)
    np.copyto(image, np.array(pil_image.convert('RGB')))
    

def draw_bounding_box_on_image(image,
                               ymin,
                               xmin,
                               ymax,
                               xmax,
                               color='red',
                               thickness=4,
                               display_str_list=(),
                               use_normalized_coordinates=True):
        
    GPIO.output(8,GPIO.HIGH)
    print('Object Detected')
    
    draw = ImageDraw.Draw(image)
    im_width, im_height = image.size
    if use_normalized_coordinates:
        (left, right, top, bottom) = (xmin * im_width, xmax * im_width,
                                      ymin * im_height, ymax * im_height)
    else:
        (left, right, top, bottom) = (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
    draw.line([(left, top), (left, bottom), (right, bottom),
               (right, top), (left, top)], width=thickness, fill=color)
    try:
        font = ImageFont.truetype('arial.ttf', 24)
    except IOError:
        font = ImageFont.load_default()

    # If the total height of the display strings added to the top of the bounding
    # box exceeds the top of the image, stack the strings below the bounding box
    # instead of above.
    display_str_heights = [font.getsize(ds)[1] for ds in display_str_list]
    # Each display_str has a top and bottom margin of 0.05x.
    total_display_str_height = (1 + 2 * 0.05) * sum(display_str_heights)

    if top > total_display_str_height:
        text_bottom = top
    else:
        text_bottom = bottom + total_display_str_height
    # Reverse list and print from bottom to top.
    for display_str in display_str_list[::-1]:
        text_width, text_height = font.getsize(display_str)
        margin = np.ceil(0.05 * text_height)
        draw.rectangle(
            [(left, text_bottom - text_height - 2 * margin), (left + text_width,
                                                              text_bottom)],
            fill=color)
        draw.text(
            (left + margin, text_bottom - text_height - margin),
            display_str,
            fill='black',
            font=font)
        text_bottom -= text_height - 2 * margin
    
def draw_bounding_box_on_image_array(image,
                                     ymin,
                                     xmin,
                                     ymax,
                                     xmax,
                                     color='red',
                                     thickness=4,
                                     display_str_list=(),
                                     use_normalized_coordinates=True):

    image_pil = Image.fromarray(np.uint8(image)).convert('RGB')
    draw_bounding_box_on_image(image_pil, ymin, xmin, ymax, xmax, color,
                               thickness, display_str_list,
                               use_normalized_coordinates)
    np.copyto(image, np.array(image_pil))
    


def draw_keypoints_on_image(image,
                            keypoints,
                            color='red',
                            radius=2,
                            use_normalized_coordinates=True):

    draw = ImageDraw.Draw(image)
    im_width, im_height = image.size
    keypoints_x = [k[1] for k in keypoints]
    keypoints_y = [k[0] for k in keypoints]
    if use_normalized_coordinates:
        keypoints_x = tuple([im_width * x for x in keypoints_x])
        keypoints_y = tuple([im_height * y for y in keypoints_y])
    for keypoint_x, keypoint_y in zip(keypoints_x, keypoints_y):
        draw.ellipse([(keypoint_x - radius, keypoint_y - radius),
                      (keypoint_x + radius, keypoint_y + radius)],
                     outline=color, fill=color)


def draw_keypoints_on_image_array(image,
                                  keypoints,
                                  color='red',
                                  radius=2,
                                  use_normalized_coordinates=True):
  
    image_pil = Image.fromarray(np.uint8(image)).convert('RGB')
    draw_keypoints_on_image(image_pil, keypoints, color, radius,
                            use_normalized_coordinates)
    np.copyto(image, np.array(image_pil))

def visualize_boxes_and_labels_on_image_array(
        image,
        boxes,
        classes,
        scores,
        category_index,
 **     scan,    **
        instance_masks=None,
        instance_boundaries=None,
        keypoints=None,
        track_ids=None,
        use_normalized_coordinates=False,
        max_boxes_to_draw=20,
        min_score_thresh=.5,
        agnostic_mode=False,
        line_thickness=4,
        groundtruth_box_visualization_color='black',
        skip_scores=False,
        skip_labels=False,
        skip_track_ids=False):
    
    GPIO.output(8,GPIO.LOW)
    
   # Create a display string (and color) for every box location, group any boxes
    # that correspond to the same location.
    box_to_display_str_map = collections.defaultdict(list)
    box_to_color_map = collections.defaultdict(str)
    box_to_instance_masks_map = {}
    box_to_instance_boundaries_map = {}
    box_to_keypoints_map = collections.defaultdict(list)
    box_to_track_ids_map = {}
    if not max_boxes_to_draw:
        max_boxes_to_draw = boxes.shape[0]
    for i in range(min(max_boxes_to_draw, boxes.shape[0])):
        if scores is None or scores[i] > min_score_thresh:
            box = tuple(boxes[i].tolist())
            if instance_masks is not None:
                box_to_instance_masks_map[box] = instance_masks[i]
            if instance_boundaries is not None:
                box_to_instance_boundaries_map[box] = instance_boundaries[i]
            if keypoints is not None:
                box_to_keypoints_map[box].extend(keypoints[i])
            if track_ids is not None:
                box_to_track_ids_map[box] = track_ids[i]
            if scores is None:
                box_to_color_map[box] = groundtruth_box_visualization_color
            else:
                display_str = ''
                if not skip_labels:
                    if not agnostic_mode:
                        if classes[i] in six.viewkeys(category_index):
                            class_name = category_index[classes[i]]['name']
                        else:
                            class_name = 'N/A'
                        display_str = str(class_name)
                if not skip_scores:
                    if not display_str:
                        display_str = '{}%'.format(int(100*scores[i]))
                    else:
                        display_str = '{}: {}%'.format(
                            display_str, int(100*scores[i]))
                if not skip_track_ids and track_ids is not None:
                    if not display_str:
                        display_str = 'ID {}'.format(track_ids[i])
                    else:
                        display_str = '{}: ID {}'.format(
                            display_str, track_ids[i])
                box_to_display_str_map[box].append(display_str)
                if agnostic_mode:
                    box_to_color_map[box] = 'DarkOrange'
                elif track_ids is not None:
                    prime_multipler = _get_multiplier_for_color_randomness()
                    box_to_color_map[box] = STANDARD_COLORS[
                        (prime_multipler * track_ids[i]) % len(STANDARD_COLORS)]
                else:
                    box_to_color_map[box] = STANDARD_COLORS[
                        classes[i] % len(STANDARD_COLORS)]

    # Draw all boxes onto image.
    for box, color in box_to_color_map.items():
        ymin, xmin, ymax, xmax = box
        if instance_masks is not None:
            draw_mask_on_image_array(
                image,
                box_to_instance_masks_map[box],
                color=color
            )
        if instance_boundaries is not None:
            draw_mask_on_image_array(
                image,
                box_to_instance_boundaries_map[box],
                color='red',
                alpha=1.0
            )        
        draw_bounding_box_on_image_array(
            image,
            ymin,
            xmin,
            ymax,
            xmax,
            color=color,
            thickness=line_thickness,
            display_str_list=box_to_display_str_map[box],
            use_normalized_coordinates=use_normalized_coordinates)
        
        **scan.value = 'f'
        print(scan.value) # output: 'f'**
        
        if keypoints is not None:
            draw_keypoints_on_image_array(
                image,
                box_to_keypoints_map[box],
                color=color,
                radius=line_thickness / 2,
                use_normalized_coordinates=use_normalized_coordinates)
    return image
```

The hope was that once an object is detected, the scan function would break. Visualization.py is executed in the detect_process, but only when an object is detected.

The statements are correctly relayed from my print statements as follows, but the loop still doesn't break:

```
$ rpi-deep-pantilt track Raspi
t
Scanning
Object Detected
f
Object Detected
f
Object Detected
f
Object Detected
f
Object Detected
f
Object Detected
f
Object Detected
f
Object Detected
f
Object Detected
f
Object Detected
f
Object Detected
f
Object Detected
f
Object Detected
f
Object Detected
f
Object Detected
f
Object Detected
f
Object Detected
f
^C
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue you're having here is that memory is (generally) not shared between portions of a multiprocessing python program. In this case, `scan_on` is a *local variable* in your manager.py script, which is then re-instantiated in the visualization.py script.

To share data between Processes, we can use [Values](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#sharing-state-between-processes). These are objectified values that allow sharing state between Processes by simply passing it as an argument.

Why? Simple values like integers and booleans are *copied* when you pass them into a function, rather than maintaining state across their multiple instances. The `Value` object, however, simply passes a *reference* to the value rather than a direct copy.

Though I don't see where you're calling `visualize_boxes_and_labels_on_image_array()`, here's a start:

```py
scan_on = manager.Value('c', 't') # the 'c' references the unsigned c-char, 
# other types found here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/array.html#module-array

# we'll edit your set_servo process to include this variable
servo_process = Process(target=set_servos, args=(pan, tilt, scan_on))
```

Whenever you call `visualize_boxes_and_labels_on_image_array()`, you'll also want to pass this **same instance of** `scan_on`. You should not have to redeclare it. To access or edit the value of `scan_on`, use the `.value` field.

```py
print(scan_on.value) # output: 't'
scan_on.value = 'f'
print(scan_on.value) # output: 'f'
```